# How to convert a string to a complete integer number in C?

Tags: c

I have tried in this way:

```
//Write a program to find out the reverse order of a given integer
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void){

//Put variables for the further proceed
int number, quotient=1, remainder;

//Declare a character array
char text[]="princeX";

//Show the message to the user
printf("Enter an integer number :");

//Taking input from the user
scanf("%d",&number);

//To find out the integer number in the reverse order
  while(quotient!=0){
  quotient=number/10;
  remainder=number%10;
  number=quotient;
  text[6] = remainder + '0';
  puts(text);
  }
//Converts the string to a whole integer
int numberUpdate=atoi(text);
printf("%d",numberUpdate);


}
```

I want to achieve: The user will give an integer number then my system will give the reverse order of the given integer number. To accomplish this goal I stored an integer into a character array but not entirely.

For the input: `123456`

Output shows like from my code:

```
prince6
prince5
prince4
prince3
prince2
prince1
```

Bu my expectation was:

```
 6
 5
 4
 3
 2
 1
```

After that, I just simply wanted to print those as an integer. But I could not do that. When I am going to transform these characters into an integer but the output shows zero. Which problem I have been made in my program and how can I solve that puzzle?

Comment: just print the `remainder + '0'` instead of the whole string `"princeX"`

Comment: `atoi("princeX")` returns `0` because `"princeX"` is not a valid number representation

Comment: You're always setting the last character, `text[6] = remainder + '0';`

Comment: just print the remainder+'0' instead of the whole string "princeX". Sir, I could not understand this statement. Can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: Now you can see the update @TomKarzes

Comment: `text[0] = remainder + '0';text[1]=0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem started with this line `text[6] = remainder + '0';
puts(text);` You only changed `text[6]`, which contains ‘X’ and then printed then whole `text`. That explains why you go
`Prince6
Prince5
Prince4
Prince3
Prince2
Prince1`
If you want to get the correct output, you should make these changes:

1. Declare another variable `i=0` before while loop.
2. Replace the problematic lines with `text[i] = remainder+‘0’; printf(“%c\n”, text[i]); i++;`

You do this because you want to replace all elements within the `text`. Then you should expect the correct output. These line  `int numberUpdate=atoi(text);
printf("%d",numberUpdate);`  will work afterward. It didn’t work at first simply because it couldn’t convert a string with letters into numbers. Since your string only contains number now, everything should work fine as expected.
I hope it was helpful for you, I did my best explaining the issue, I hope you can understand by reading it. :)))

Comment: Thank you for your facilitation. Your answer helps me and my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have number to string conversion function.

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str, *end;
    if(str)
    {
        end = str + strlen(str) -1;
        while(end > str)
        {
            char tmp = *wrk;
            *wrk++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

char digits[] = "01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstxyvwz";

char *convert(char *buff, unsigned long long val, int radix)
{
    char *tmp = buff;

    if(radix > sizeof(digits) - 1 || radix < 2) return NULL;

    while(val)
    {
        *tmp++ = digits[val % radix];
        val /= radix;
    }
    *tmp = 0;
    return reverse(buff);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[30];

    printf("decimal: %s\n", convert(str, 345676, 10));
    printf("binary: %s\n", convert(str, 345676, 2));
    printf("octal: %s\n", convert(str, 345676, 8));
    printf("hex: %s\n", convert(str, 345676, 16));
    printf("Base 5: %s\n", convert(str, 345676, 5));
    printf("Base 29: %s\n", convert(str, 345676, 29));

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6Ge6bs

Comment: It is complicated for  me to understand. Please provide some explanation of what you had done in your code.